# $x^4-(a+b+c+d)x^3-(a+b+c)x^2-(a+b)x-a=0$,then the number of integer roots in the equation is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let a,b,c,d be natural numbers.Now consider an equation
>
> $x^4-(a+b+c+d)x^3-(a+b+c)x^2-(a+b)x-a=0$,then the number of integer
>   roots in the equation is ?

Me: Plugged in $0,1,-1$.No use.At 0 the sign is negative and at infinity the sign is positive. At least one real root.Not sure if that will be integer though :/.Help please!

Comment: The rational root theorem could help, but do you have any other constraints on $a,b,c,d$? Otherwise I think you can construct examples with $0,1,2,3,$ or $4$ integer roots.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish No.are you quite sure about that(example thing)? Its an exam question..don't think it would be so silly :-P

Comment: It has no integer roots if $a=b=c=d=2$, so perhaps there is a way to show it will never have integer roots.

Comment: hope so..... @CuddlyCuttlefish

Comment: Let the polynomial be $P(x)$. We can show that $P(0) = -a < 0$ and $P(-1) = 1+b+d > 0$. With a bit of algebra, we can show that $P'(x) \le 0$ for $x \le -1$. This rules out the possibility of a non-positive integer root. Also, Descartes Rule of Signs tells us that there is at most 1 positive root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(x) = x^4-(a+b+c+d)x^3-(a+b+c)x^2-(a+b)x-a$.

For $x \le -1$, we have $-x \le x^2$, and thus, $P'(x) = 4x^3-3(a+b+c+d)x^2-2(a+b+c)x-(a+b)$ $\le 4x^3-(a+b+c+3d)x^2-(a+b) < 0$.

Then, since $P(-1) = 1+b+d > 0$, we have that $P(x) > 0$ for all $x \le -1$, and thus, $P(x)$ has no negative integer roots.

Trivially, $P(0) = -a < 0$, so $0$ is not a root of $P(x)$.

By Descartes Rule of signs, $P(x)$ has at exactly one positive root.

However, $P(a+b+c+d) = -(a+b+c)(a+b+c+d)^2-(a+b)(a+b+c+d)-a < 0$, and since $P(x) \ge x^4-(a+b+c+d)(x^3+x^2+x+1) = x^4-(a+b+c+d)\dfrac{x^4-1}{x-1}$ for $x \ge 0$, we have $P(a+b+c+d+1) \ge 1$.

Thus, the one positive root of $P(x)$ is not an integer.

Therefore, $P(x)$ has no integer roots.

Comment: There is a tiny (insignificant?) mistake. It should be By Descartes Rule of signs, $P(x)$ has EXACTLY one positive root.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the equation has an integer root $x$.  By @JimmyK4542's comment we have $x>0$; also, $x\mid a$ so $x\le a$.  Clearly
$$x-(a+b+c)<0$$
and so
$$d=\frac{x^4-(a+b+c)x^3-(a+b+c)x^2-(a+b)x-a}{x^3}<0\ .$$
This is a contradiction.